# D3: get horizontal position of ticks

Tags: d3.js

So I am using an ordinal scale for my x-axis of a bar chart in D3, which I have shifted so that the ticks are under the center of their respective bars. Since some of the categories have somewhat lengthy names, I have opted to rotate the text labels and set the text anchor to the end. However rotating the text fields messes up the alignment for the axis. So I was curious as to if there was a way to get the horizontal x tick locations so that way I can just map the text field locations to the corresponding tick location and get perfectly centered rotated text labels.

## UPDATE

See the following Fiddle (Code is longer the SO permits)

https://jsfiddle.net/SumNeuron/fzk6eyy2/

```
"code" so I can post this
```

Alternatively, view code for it here:

https://bl.ocks.org/SumNeuron/7989abb1749fc70b39f7b1e8dd192248

and demo:

https://bl.ocks.org/SumNeuron/raw/7989abb1749fc70b39f7b1e8dd192248/

Comment: Yes, there is a way. However, you have to provide *your* code. Besides that, why don't you simply use a band scale instead? It would save you all this trouble.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I know it is customary to provide a M.W.E. however given the more verbose nature of D3, and this - hopefully fairly trivial - matter I thought such would be more cumbersome to the question than just asking specifically about extracting the x coordinates from the ticks.  As for why not us a band scale? I did not know that existed until now. I was working through the D3 book (published with Manning) and it has not yet mentioned the band scale (and is outdated for v4)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado code is now available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `x` and `y` position, as well as the `text-anchor` style, in the same selection you get the texts:

```
d3_selection.selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("transform","rotate(-45)")
```

Here is the demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v0.7.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-collection.v0.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v0.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-format.v0.5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v0.5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v0.6.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v0.6.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-axis.v0.2.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v0.6.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    line, path, .domain, .bar {
      stroke: black;
      fill: none;
    }
    text{
      fill: black;
    }
    
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 110, left: 10};
    var width = 500;
    var height = 400;
    var chartWidth = 500 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var chartHeight = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var axisHeight = 30;
    var data = [
      {key:'Long text', value: 1},
      {key:'Text', value: 3},
      {key:'Long long text', value: 2},
      {key:'Text', value: 3},
      {key:'Some long long text', value: 4},
    ];
    
  var scaleX = d3_scale.scaleBand()
     .domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.key; }))
     .range([0, chartWidth])
     .paddingInner([0.1])
     .paddingOuter([0.3])
     .align([0.5]);
    
    var scaleY = d3_scale.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3_array.max(data.map(function(d){ return d.value; }))])
      .range([0, chartHeight]);
    
    var axis = d3_axis.axisBottom(scaleX)
     .tickSizeInner(4)
     .tickSizeOuter(20)
     .tickPadding(3);
      
    
    
    
    var panel = d3_selection.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
     .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate("+[margin.left, margin.top]+")")
    
    panel.attr("transform", "translate("+[margin.left, height - margin.bottom]+")")
      .call(axis);
      
    
    panel.selectAll('rect.bar')
     .data(data)
     .enter().append('rect')
     .attr("class", "bar")
     .attr("width", scaleX.bandwidth())
     .attr("height", function(d){ return scaleY(d.value); })
     .attr("x", function(d){ return scaleX(d.key); })
     .attr("y", function(d){ return -scaleY(d.value); })
      
      
    d3_selection.selectAll("text").attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("transform","rotate(-45)")
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is that font size sensitive? It appears so because of the hard coded shift of y:4 x:-4... Hence why I rather just have the text be placed at the tick location for a more robust solution

Comment: I put that padding just to avoid the texts being over the ticks, which is visually ugly. You can simply remove that padding, if you want. It doesn't change the *robustness* of the solution.

Comment: I tried your approach and the result did not work :( please see the well commented code in linked Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/SumNeuron/fzk6eyy2/.

Comment: I am using `text-anchor:end`, and `scaleBand()`

Comment: That's simply because you are not using my approach in your fiddle. My approach does work, as you can easily see in the S.O. snippet. Check your modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rurffncw/

Comment: So it was `.attr("x",0).attr("y", 0)`?

Comment: Yes. If you set the position in the translate attribute of the transform function, the rotation will be made around the **center** of the element, which is not what you want. Set the position using separate attributes.

Comment: It does seem off however when changing between data

Comment: Also you seem quite knowledgeable about d3. Could you maybe give me some pointers regarding the code at  https://bl.ocks.org/SumNeuron/7989abb1749fc70b39f7b1e8dd192248

Comment: It was the transition that was messing up your solution